# Why I got value 0 when using intval() to this statement (PHP)

Tags: php, int, echo

```
<?php

    $sample01 = "3 hours with Mustang";
    echo intval($sample01)."<br/>";

    $sample02 = "Grand Total: $2,802.60";
    echo intval($sample02)."<br/>";

?>
```

When I echo `intval($sample01)` , it prints 3 as a result which is right, just like what my book says.

But when I echo `intval($sample02)`, it prints 0 !!! I am so confused. Shouldn't it print 2,802 ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):
>
> > If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

Answer (score 1):

It is because the value of `$sample02` starts with string. When it gets an `alphabet` it converts it to `0`. For `$sample01`, it starts with `3` so it prints 3 and the rest is ignored.

Comment: Your comment helps a lot. Thank you.